# How to display mapped data as list in react table

Tags: javascript, html, sql, reactjs

i want to show list of job id to single member id in react table

[image]

Comment: add image to question itself

Comment: i am new to stack overflow hence they arent allowing me to display image rather provided a link.
if this table can help...
Member ID Job ID
403 52
405 5
407 10
410 12
413 42
405 52
414 52
414 46
414 42
413 5
413 10

Comment: check my answer below, added img for you too. if helped, consider upvoting, checking as accepted

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a map member id to job ids, then you need to create a map structure:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const arr = [
    { memberId: 413, jobId: 42 },
    { memberId: 405, jobId: 52 },
  ];

  let memberIdToJobsMap = {};
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    memberIdToJobsMap[el.memberId] =  memberIdToJobsMap[el.memberId] || [];
    memberIdToJobsMap[el.memberId].push(el.jobId);
  });


  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(memberIdToJobsMap).map((memberId) => (
        <div key={memberId}>
          {memberId}:  {memberIdToJobsMap[memberId].join(", "))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to display multiple Job IDs as a list for single Member ID

Comment: for ex.---------  Member ID - 413   Job ID - 43,44,54

Comment: check now, you need to build map then member id to job ids and loop then

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyComponent() {
  const arr = [
    { memberId: 413, jobId: 42 },
    { memberId: 405, jobId: 52 },
  ];

  return (

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Member id</th>
                <th>Job id</th>
            </tr>
            {arr.map((el) => {
                return(
                    <tr key={el.memberId}>
                        <td>{el.memberId}</td>
                        <td>{el.jobId}</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })}
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat your data.

```
const groupedData = {};

  data.forEach((row) => {
    if (!groupedData[row.memberId]) {
      groupedData[row.memberId] = [];
    }

    groupedData[row.memberId].push(row.jobId);
  });
```

Full Example:

```
const data = [
  { memberId: 414, jobId: 1 },
  { memberId: 404, jobId: 2 },
  { memberId: 414, jobId: 3 },
  { memberId: 411, jobId: 6 },
  { memberId: 412, jobId: 7 },
  { memberId: 404, jobId: 8 }
];

export default function App() {
  const tableHeader = Object.keys(data[0]);
  const groupedData = {};

  data.forEach((row) => {
    if (!groupedData[row.memberId]) {
      groupedData[row.memberId] = [];
    }

    groupedData[row.memberId].push(row.jobId);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((key) => (
            <th>{key}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
        {Object.keys(groupedData).map((key) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{key}</td>
            <td>{groupedData[key].join(", ")}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a live example:

[image: Edit objective-gagarin-480lzf]

Answer (score 0):

First, you a need memoized data object grouped by **memberId**.

```js
  const jobsByMemberId = useMemo(() => {
    return data.reduce(
      (result, item) => ({
        ...result,
        [item.memberId]: [...(result[item.memberId] || []), item.jobId],
      }),
      {}
    );
  }, []);
```

And then, convert that into memoized **rows** array that depends on **jobsByMemberId**

```js
  const rows = useMemo(() => {
    return Object.keys(jobsByMemberId).map((key) => {
      return { memberId: key, jobIds: jobsByMemberId[key] };
    });
  }, [jobsByMemberId]);
```

and then you can render the table by mapping the rows data:

```
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Member ID</th>
          <th>Jobs ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{row.memberId}</td>
              <td>{row.jobIds.join(",")}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
```

You can see the result by running the code snippet below.

```js
const { useEffect, useMemo } = React;

const data = [
{ memberId: 413, jobId: 42 },
{ memberId: 405, jobId: 52 },
{ memberId: 414, jobId: 52 },
{ memberId: 414, jobId: 46 },
{ memberId: 414, jobId: 42 },
{ memberId: 413, jobId: 5 },
{ memberId: 413, jobId: 10 },
{ memberId: 413, jobId: 5 },
{ memberId: 413, jobId: 5 },
];

function App() {
    const jobsByMemberId = useMemo(() => {
        return data.reduce(
            (result, item) => ({
            ...result,
            [item.memberId]: [...(result[item.memberId] || []), item.jobId],
            }),
            {}
        );
    }, []);

    const jobs = useMemo(() => {
        return Object.keys(jobsByMemberId).map((key) => {
            return { memberId: key, jobIds: jobsByMemberId[key] };
        });
    }, [jobsByMemberId]);

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Member ID</th>
                    <th>Jobs ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {jobs.map((job, index) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{job.memberId}</td>
                        <td>{job.jobIds.join(",")}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```